# Using Python to combine middle parts of two fields into third field

Tags: python, arcpy

Below is how I used the Update Cursor in my final script. As you can see getValue was used a few times, perhaps there is a cleaner way to do this? But my concatenated field wouldn't populate properly otherwise.

```
    sourceRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inFeatures)
    source = sourceRows.next() 

    while source:
        fieldString1 = source.getValue(fieldName1)
        fieldString2 = source.getValue(fieldName2)
        concatString= (str(source.getValue(fieldName2))[1:7] + str(source.getValue(fieldName1))[1:7])
        source.setValue(fieldName3, concatString)
        sourceRows.updateRow(source)
        source = sourceRows.next()
    del source, sourceRows
```

I have a script that creates three fields in a feature class. The script adds the X and Y coordinates to the first two fields. I would like data found in the middle parts of the first two fields to populate the third field. Does anyone know how to find the middle part of a field using Python? I see where VBScript seems to have a MID function but I haven't found anything for Python yet. Below is what the third field (fieldName3) should look like.

```
fieldName1     fieldName2   fieldName3
12345.321       36789.321   67892345
24680.5425      98765.432   87654680
```

Do you see how I want data to be combined in fieldName3? Below is the script as I have it now.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = "D:/gisfiles/test.gdb/"

inFeatures = "fc"
fieldName1 = "xCoord"
fieldName2 = "yCoord"
fieldName3 = "Combined"
fieldPrecision = 18
fieldScale = 11

expression1 = "float(!SHAPE.CENTROID!.split()[0])"
expression2 = "float(!SHAPE.CENTROID!.split()[1])"

arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName1, "DOUBLE", fieldPrecision, fieldScale)
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName2, "DOUBLE", fieldPrecision, fieldScale)
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, fieldName3, "DOUBLE", fieldPrecision, fieldScale)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, fieldName1, expression1,
                            "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, fieldName2, expression2,
                            "PYTHON")

sourceRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inFeatures)
source = sourceRows.next()

while source:
        **#Instead of 12345 I need an expression to combine fieldName1 and fieldName2**
        source.setValue(fieldName3, "12345")
        sourceRows.updateRow(source)
        source = sourceRows.next()
del source, sourceRows
```

Comment: You could [slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) out the parts you want, then concatentate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can populate fieldName3 by using string slicing and concatenation, as Chap Cooper recommended.

Here is essentially what you want to do:

```
while source:
    source.setValue(fieldName3, str(fieldname2)[1:5] + str(fieldname1)[1:5])
    sourceRows.updateRow(source)
    source = sourceRows.next()
del source, sourceRows
```

Comment: If `fieldname1` and `fieldname2` are floating point numbers, then expect "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". To avoid this error, you need to cast them to a string using `str()`.

Comment: I got my script to work properly! I utilized slicing and concatenation as you described, Casey. I also had to use getValue a few times for it to populate the field properly - as you can see in my initial question. Thank you for the replies!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to round your coordinates and and have a bit more flexibility on lengths of character used for each coordinate, try this function:

```
def short_coord(x, y, len=4):
    div = 10**len
    return (str(int(round(x, 0) % div)).rjust(len, '0') + 
            str(int(round(y, 0) % div)).rjust(len, '0'))
```

You can test it out:

```
>>> short_coord(98765.432, 24680.5425)
'87654681'
>>> short_coord(95.432, 120.5425, len=3)
'095021'
```

Note: I assume the inputs are floating point numbers, and the expected output is a string. Also, in case you are wondering, `%` is the handy [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

possibly change it to:

```
sourceRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inFeatures)  
for source in sourceRows:    
    source.fieldName3 == str(fieldname2)[1:5] + str(fieldname1)[1:5])
    sourceRows.updateRow(source)     
    del source

del sourceRows
```

if `source.setValue` doesn't work, which occassionally it doesn't, for whatever reason...

Comment: Tis was meant as a comment to the answer above, but it wouldn't format, so I put it here.  If you want me to delete it, please just make a comment and I will, please do not simply downmark for copying the answer, it's not meant as an answer.  Cheers!